# Plotly dash_auth.BasicAuth "if req.status_code != 200:" Exception

Tags: python, authentication, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I am using the basic auth for Plotly Dash for a simple classroom demonstration. Without the auth line of code, everything runs correctly as expected, but the moment it's added I get a confusing Exception. Here is my code (with some unimportant file paths taken out):

```
app = Dash(__name__)

auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(app, {'user1':'123456789'})

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1(children = 'Find Your True Self', id = 'title'),    
    html.H2('A personality selector',id = 'title2'),            
    html.H3('Visualizations of the world\'s personalities', style = {'textAlign': 'center'}),     
    dcc.Dropdown(options = [
        {'label':'Average Personalities' ,'value': 1},
        {'label': 'Survey','value': 2}],
        id = 'drop',
        value = 1),                               
    html.Div(id = 'graph')

], className = 'container_class', id = 'container_id')
#!------------------------------------------Layout ends, callbacks begin----------------------------------------------------
@callback(
    Output('graph','children'),
    Input('drop', 'value')
)
def show_graph(input_value):
    if input_value == 1:
        return html.Iframe(srcDoc = open(r'graph.html', encoding = 'utf-8').read(), width = 600, height = 500)
    else: 
        df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Yes': 2439784,
        'No': 6478909
        },index = range(1))
        
        fig = px.bar(x = df.columns, y = df.loc[0], color = df.columns, template = 'plotly_dark', title = 'Survey: Do You Agree With Your Assigned Personality? ', labels = list(df.columns), width = 600, height = 400)
        fig.update_layout(
        xaxis_title= 'Yes or No',
        yaxis_title= 'Total')

        return dcc.Graph(figure = fig)


        
app.run(port = '8051', debug = True, jupyter_mode = 'external')
```

This is the Exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 41
     33         fig.update_layout(
     34         xaxis_title= 'Yes or No',
     35         yaxis_title= 'Total')
     37         return dcc.Graph(figure = fig)
---> 41 app.run(port = '8051', debug = True, jupyter_mode = 'external')

File c:\Users\six6i\anaconda3\envs\Dash\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py:2066, in Dash.run(self, host, port, proxy, debug, jupyter_mode, jupyter_width, jupyter_height, jupyter_server_url, dev_tools_ui, dev_tools_props_check, dev_tools_serve_dev_bundles, dev_tools_hot_reload, dev_tools_hot_reload_interval, dev_tools_hot_reload_watch_interval, dev_tools_hot_reload_max_retry, dev_tools_silence_routes_logging, dev_tools_prune_errors, **flask_run_options)
   2063             extra_files.append(path)
   2065 if jupyter_dash.active:
-> 2066     jupyter_dash.run_app(
   2067         self,
   2068         mode=jupyter_mode,
   2069         width=jupyter_width,
   2070         height=jupyter_height,
   2071         host=host,
   2072         port=port,
   2073         server_url=jupyter_server_url,
   2074     )
   2075 else:
   2076     self.server.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)

File c:\Users\six6i\anaconda3\envs\Dash\lib\site-packages\dash\_jupyter.py:401, in JupyterDash.run_app(self, app, mode, width, height, host, port, server_url)
    399     display(HTML(msg))
    400 else:
--> 401     raise final_error

File c:\Users\six6i\anaconda3\envs\Dash\lib\site-packages\dash\_jupyter.py:388, in JupyterDash.run_app(self, app, mode, width, height, host, port, server_url)
    385         raise err
    387 try:
--> 388     wait_for_app()
    390     if self.in_colab:
    391         JupyterDash._display_in_colab(dashboard_url, port, mode, width, height)

File c:\Users\six6i\anaconda3\envs\Dash\lib\site-packages\retrying.py:56, in retry.<locals>.wrap.<locals>.wrapped_f(*args, **kw)
     54 @six.wraps(f)
     55 def wrapped_f(*args, **kw):
---> 56     return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)

File c:\Users\six6i\anaconda3\envs\Dash\lib\site-packages\retrying.py:266, in Retrying.call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
    263 if self.stop(attempt_number, delay_since_first_attempt_ms):
    264     if not self._wrap_exception and attempt.has_exception:
    265         # get() on an attempt with an exception should cause it to be raised, but raise just in case
--> 266         raise attempt.get()
    267     else:
    268         raise RetryError(attempt)

File c:\Users\six6i\anaconda3\envs\Dash\lib\site-packages\retrying.py:301, in Attempt.get(self, wrap_exception)
    299         raise RetryError(self)
    300     else:
--> 301         six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
    302 else:
    303     return self.value

File c:\Users\six6i\anaconda3\envs\Dash\lib\site-packages\six.py:719, in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    717     if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    718         raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 719     raise value
    720 finally:
    721     value = None

File c:\Users\six6i\anaconda3\envs\Dash\lib\site-packages\retrying.py:251, in Retrying.call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
    248     self._before_attempts(attempt_number)
    250 try:
--> 251     attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
    252 except:
    253     tb = sys.exc_info()

File c:\Users\six6i\anaconda3\envs\Dash\lib\site-packages\dash\_jupyter.py:375, in JupyterDash.run_app.<locals>.wait_for_app()
    373 res = req.content.decode()
    374 if req.status_code != 200:
--> 375     raise Exception(res)
    377 if res != "Alive":
    378     url = f"http://{host}:{port}"

Exception:
```

These are my dependencies:

```
Package                Version
---------------------- ------------
ansi2html              1.9.1
asttokens              2.4.1
backcall               0.2.0
blinker                1.7.0
Brotli                 1.1.0
certifi                2023.11.17
charset-normalizer     3.3.2
click                  8.1.7
colorama               0.4.6
comm                   0.2.1
dash                   2.14.2
dash-auth              2.0.0
dash-core-components   2.0.0
dash-html-components   2.0.0
dash-table             5.0.0
debugpy                1.6.7
decorator              5.1.1
executing              2.0.1
Flask                  3.0.0
Flask-Compress         1.14
Flask-SeaSurf          1.1.1
idna                   3.6
importlib-metadata     7.0.1
ipykernel              6.28.0
ipython                8.12.0
itsdangerous           2.1.2
jedi                   0.19.1
Jinja2                 3.1.2
jupyter_client         8.6.0
jupyter_core           4.12.0
MarkupSafe             2.1.3
matplotlib-inline      0.1.6
mysql-connector-python 8.2.0
nest-asyncio           1.5.8
numpy                  1.26.3
packaging              23.2
pandas                 2.1.4
parso                  0.8.3
pickleshare            0.7.5
pip                    23.3.1
plotly                 5.18.0
prompt-toolkit         3.0.42
protobuf               4.21.12
psutil                 5.9.0
pure-eval              0.2.2
Pygments               2.17.2
python-dateutil        2.8.2
pytz                   2023.3.post1
pywin32                227
pyzmq                  25.1.0
requests               2.31.0
retrying               1.3.4
setuptools             68.2.2
six                    1.16.0
stack-data             0.6.2
tenacity               8.2.3
tornado                6.2
traitlets              5.14.1
typing_extensions      4.9.0
tzdata                 2023.4
ua-parser              0.18.0
urllib3                2.1.0
wcwidth                0.2.12
Werkzeug               3.0.1
wheel                  0.41.2
zipp                   3.17.0
```

I am running my code in VSCode in an ipynb. The last time I got the basic auth to work was before they did away with the JupyterDash library and integrated it into the base Dash (I think my Dash version was 2.7.0 back then).

I tried changing the versions of Dash to 12.14.1 like the have on the [tutorial](https://dash.plotly.com/authentication) to no avail.

Thank you for your time and I appreciate your help!